# Nested while loop runs only once

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli, while-loop

Nested "**while**" loop runs only one time, **only one** div is displayed, can't find any mistakes, **0** errors in "**error_log**". Feel free to suggest.

I need second sql connection, because **$connectToStore** makes mysqli connection with separate database.

**$items looks like  1-2,2-5,9-1**

**I've checked and div that's displayed uses data which is in the first row of the table**

PHP

```
include("connect.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sp_tickets WHERE user_id='foo'";
$sqlresult = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($sqlresult) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult)) {

    $sqlStore = "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE order_id='".$row['order_id']."'";
    $connectToStore = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "root_db");
    $sqlStoreDBResult = mysqli_query($connectToStore, $sqlStore);

    while ($rowTr = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlStoreDBResult)) {

        $id_str_array = $rowTr['items'];
        $id_str_array = rtrim($id_str_array, ",");
        $id_str_array = explode(',', $id_str_array);
        foreach ($id_str_array as $key => $value) {
            $id_quantity_pair = explode("-", $value); // Uses Hyphen(-) as delimiter to separate product ID from its quantity
            $product_id = $id_quantity_pair[0]; // Get the product ID

            $sqlProduct = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$product_id'";
            $sqlresult = mysqli_query($connectToStore, $sqlProduct);
            while ($pp_row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult)) {

                $tickets .= '<div class="holder">
                <div data-ticket="' . $ticket . '" class="ticket">
                    <div class="ticket-left">
                        <span class="product-ticket left-span">' . $pp_row['product_name'] . ' ' . $pp_row['product_platform'] . ' ' . $pp_row['product_type'] . ' ' . $pp_row['product_region'] . '</span>
                        <span class="ticket-no left-span">Ticket No. ' . $row['ticket_id'] . '</span>
                        <span class="order-no left-span">Order No. ' . $row['order_id'] . '</span>
                        <span class="left-span">Transaction No. ' . $rowTr['txn_id'] . '</span>
                        <span class="product-region left-span">Region: ' . $pp_row['product_region'] . '</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ticket-right">
                        <span class="created">Created: ' . $row['date'] . '</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ticket-bottom">
                        <div class="bottom-holder">
                            <span class="details"><span class="subject-txt">Category: </span>' . $row['category'] . '</span>
                            <span class="details"><span class="subject-txt">Subject: </span>' . $row['subject'] . '</span>
                            <span class="details desc">"' . $row['description'] . '"</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="removeticketcontainer">
                    <span class="removeticket">X</span>
                </div>
             </div>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @The One and Only ChemistryBlob Yes, it's unique

Comment: Where is `$tickets` declared?

Comment: if you haven't defined `$tickets` somehwere above `$tickets .= '..'` should throw an error? And where does $ticket come from?

Comment: Technically you don't need two DB connections, if the DB user has privilege to access both Databases, and you prefix the other table with the DB, so you connect to DB `a` and then for the query in DB `b` you just do `b.table`.  In MySql you can even Join across DB's, although its probably not a "Best" practice to do that.

Comment: I'm assuming different DB connect params

Comment: Wow the 2nd DB connnection is renewed EACH time.  OMG.  and if your error_log is empty then you are in the wrong error log.  Because `$tickets` DEFINITELY throws a warning error.  Are you looking in /var/logs/httpd?

Comment: Further I would avoid doing a DB connection inside of a loop.  `while ... mysqli_connect("localhost" ...`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include **$ticket**. I have declared **$tickets = "";** At the top of the **php** file.

Comment: I did put connection **outside** of while loop, still nothing changes.

Comment: @EasternEuropean What does this give you `mysqli_num_rows($sqlresult);` Do this right before the while loop.

Comment: Can you pl. confirm if you are getting multiple values for $pp_row?

Comment: The problem looks like you are overwriting the variable $sqlresult with a new result that only returns 1 row. Try to change that in the nested loop.

Comment: @ckimbrell Good mention! Haven't thought about that! Now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Answer belongs to **@ckimbrell**. "The problem looks like you are overwriting the variable $sqlresult with a new result that only returns 1 row. Try to change that in the nested loop."

```
include("connect.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sp_tickets WHERE user_id='foo'";
$sqlresult = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

$connectToStore = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "root_db");

if (mysqli_num_rows($sqlresult) > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult)) {

$sqlStore = "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE order_id='".$row['order_id']."'";
$sqlStoreDBResult = mysqli_query($connectToStore, $sqlStore);

while ($rowTr = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlStoreDBResult)) {

    $id_str_array = $rowTr['items'];
    $id_str_array = rtrim($id_str_array, ",");
    $id_str_array = explode(',', $id_str_array);
    foreach ($id_str_array as $key => $value) {
        $id_quantity_pair = explode("-", $value); // Uses Hyphen(-) as delimiter to separate product ID from its quantity
        $product_id = $id_quantity_pair[0]; // Get the product ID

        $sqlProduct = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$product_id'";
        $sqlresult2 = mysqli_query($connectToStore, $sqlProduct);
        while ($pp_row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult2)) {

            $tickets .= '<div class="holder">
            <div data-ticket="' . $ticket . '" class="ticket">
                <div class="ticket-left">
                    <span class="product-ticket left-span">' . $pp_row['product_name'] . ' ' . $pp_row['product_platform'] . ' ' . $pp_row['product_type'] . ' ' . $pp_row['product_region'] . '</span>
                    <span class="ticket-no left-span">Ticket No. ' . $row['ticket_id'] . '</span>
                    <span class="order-no left-span">Order No. ' . $row['order_id'] . '</span>
                    <span class="left-span">Transaction No. ' . $rowTr['txn_id'] . '</span>
                    <span class="product-region left-span">Region: ' . $pp_row['product_region'] . '</span>
                </div>
                <div class="ticket-right">
                    <span class="created">Created: ' . $row['date'] . '</span>
                </div>
                <div class="ticket-bottom">
                    <div class="bottom-holder">
                        <span class="details"><span class="subject-txt">Category: </span>' . $row['category'] . '</span>
                        <span class="details"><span class="subject-txt">Subject: </span>' . $row['subject'] . '</span>
                        <span class="details desc">"' . $row['description'] . '"</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="removeticketcontainer">
                <span class="removeticket">X</span>
            </div>
         </div>';
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your outermost while is only fetching one record

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult)) {
 . . . . 
}
```

Get rid of the outermost while if you only fetch one record...

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult);// remove closing } too
```